# how to bind a list of tuples using Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have some queries like this:

```
List listOfIntegers = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1, 2, 3});
List objects = 
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query("select * from bla where id in ( :ids )",
            Collections.singletonMap("ids", listOfIntegers),
            myRowMapper);
```

This will send this SQL query to the database:

```
select * from bla where id in ( 1, 2, 3 )
```

Now I want to send this type of query to the database:

```
select * from bla where (id,name) in ( (1,'foo'), (2,'bar'), (3,'foobar'))
```

Do I need to pass a List<List<Object>> to accomplish this? Will it work with Spring JDBCTemplate?

Comment: Tested with List<List<Object>> and it did not work. Debugging the Spring code that handles the list of integers I saw that it generates a series of '?' for each element in the list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have debugged Spring code and found that it expects tuples to be provided as Object[], so for it to work with a List it should be a List<Object[]>.

Comment: Hi, could you take a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877193/spring-jpa-repository-jpql-query-using-a-collection-of-objects

Comment: it doesn't work for me :(