# Spring JPA repository JPQL query using a collection of objects

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

let's say I have the next entity or object:

```
class Person {    
  BigInteger cardNumber;
  String name;
  int age;
  Address address;
}
```

Then, I have a `List<Person>` and I want to find the youngest person based on the `cardNumber` and `name`. So, I'd like to write a query similar to this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.cardNumber = :myPerson.cardNumber AND p.name LIKE :myPerson.name ORDER BY p.age ASC")
public List<Person> find(@param("myPerson") List<Person> personList);
```

My problem is that I'm not so sure how to tackle this, and what approach to use. I've tried passing two collections, `List<String> names` and `List<BigInteger> cardNumbers` and the query was something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.cardNumber IN (:cardNumbers) AND p.name IN (:names) ORDER BY p.age ASC")
public List<Person> find(@param("cardNumbers") List<BigInteger> cardNumbers, @param("names") List<String> names);
```

The problem, I need to use the `name` and the `cardNumber` as a single value to compare because, they both work as a primary key. I tried to `CONCAT(name, cardNumber)` and pass to the method a list of strings with the `name.concat(cardNumber.toString(())` value but, I found that the JPQL turns the `BigInteger` in a number like this `1.00` so, to make it work I need to do something like this `name.concat(cardNumber.toString(() + ".00")`. That way, it works but, I can't hardcode that mapping from `BigInteger` to `String`.

Any advice is appreciated. I just want to find a way to pass the collection of the object rather than concatenate those strings in my code and then pass them to the query method.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using `BigInteger` for `cardNumber`?

Comment: @chrylis It's just an example because the project has that data type and I can't change it.

Comment: How would you write your query in SQL?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'd write something like this: `SELECT * FROM Person p WHERE (p.name, p.cardNumber) IN (('MyName', 1), ('OtherName', 2) ...)`

Comment: @andresscode did you ever figure this out? I have a pretty similar problem trying to make a bulk delete operation for my entity table annotation with `@IdClass`.

Comment: @payne Unfortunately, I did not continue working on this.